# Convert ps to pdf by ps2pdf, but the pdf file is not well-behaved

Tags: pdf, ps, conversion

I have [a ps file](http://dl.dropbox.com/u/13029929/elden.ps),and converted it to [a pdf file](http://dl.dropbox.com/u/13029929/elden.pdf) using ps2pdf.

> ps2pdf elden.ps elden.pdf

When I open the pdf file in evince, and try to select some text in it using my mouse, the selected content is not the text but some incomprehensible symbols, and also it cost a lot of memory for opening the ps and pdf files and a lot of CPU time for selecting.

I was wondering how to convert the ps to a pdf file whose text can be selected and copied, and without much memory and cpu time?

Comment: How was the `ps` originally created?

Comment: If the PostScript file is not just a raster image, you should be able to translate into Portable Document Format without much changes.

Comment: @Bernhard: probabily using some strange package in LaTex (not by me).

Comment: @vonbrand: you can try to convert the ps file to pdf. Then you will understand my questions.

Comment: Got the file, it is a regular PS with raster fonts (generated from a TeX DVI file). (Open with `less`, check the `%%Creator:` line). The fonts look like Computer Modern (see `%DVIPSBitmapFont: Fa lcmssi8 16.59 10`). Yes, copy&paste gives gibberish. Not that I've ever been able to get sense out of `evince` copy&paste, had much more luck with `xpdf` (no, that doesn't work here, and it complains that the glyphs have bad bounding boxes). `pdftotext` also gives gibberish. Perhaps at http://tex.stackexchange.com you'll have better luck? You could request the question to be migrated.

Comment: The original PS is upside down...

Comment: @vonbrand:(1) after ps2pdf, the pdf is not upside down. (2) although the ps was probably generated from LaTex by the author, I only have the ps file not the tex file. So I am not sure if my questions are okay at tex.SE?

Comment: I see the PS upside down. tex.SE is the handiest place where you _might_ find people with the expertise to decompile the PS, but I'm pretty sure they will answer as I do: Type it again if you need the formulas.

Comment: Go back to the sources and directly create PDF from them.

Comment: @MartinSchröder:Idon't have the source.

Comment: Tim, this is the usual behavior of many TeX articles/books/whatever (tex->dvi->ps->pdf, although one can go from tex to pdf directly without these troubles). To convert to a normal, selectable pdf, barring having the source (which you don't), the only way is to pass this file through OCR.

Answer (score 3):

This is Fedora 18, up to date.

The original PS file is math-heavy (it is a set of 28 slides, created from a TeX DVI file with raster fonts). It reads fine in `evince` (but upside down), and the result of `ps2pdf` also reads fine in `evince` and `xpdf`.

At most you could hope to get the (scanty) text on the slides, most of it is math that won't translate at all into understandable text, even under ideal circumstances, much less into formulas. The only way to make that into LaTeX math formulas again (or whatever other format you'd like) is to retype them.